# why won't all font awesome icons load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

i've got font-awesome-rails running and seemingly working correctly, but, not all icons are loading, probably only about half, any thoughts on what is going wrong ?

[image]

in the above screenshot, the chrome inspector highlight element `<i class="icon-mobile survicon icon">` should make a mobile something or other font icon appear under the calendar looking one.

i'm rendering icons in the view per the below, standard rails stuff.

```
  - answer[0].each do |a,i|
    .row.surveyselection{data: { answerId: "#{index}"}}
      .large-2.columns.outline.center
        = fa_icon "#{i.to_s}", class: "survicon icon"
      .large-10.columns.outline.flushleft.surveyq.middle
        = a
```

thoughts on what i'm missing out on ?

Comment: What version of font-awesome are you running?  Font awesome recently updated their CSS classes, so that rather than 'icon-mobile' you'd use 'fa fa-mobile' to display the mobile icon.  You can find more info at the Font Awesome site.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like version issues.  Font Awesome 4.0 was just released and has new naming conventions, so make sure you're not using the wrong class names.  More info below.

Font Awesome 4.0:
http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Font Awesome 3.2.1:
http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icons/